# File created by shell script is not opened by python?

Tags: python

`echo "Denied" > log.txt`

later log.txt is opened  in python:

```
def read_file(logs,self):
    print 'here'
    f1=open(logs,"r","utf-8")
    for line in f1:
        print str(line)
```

On running it gives error:

```
"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it probably should be:

```
def read_file(self, logs):
```

with the reverse parameter order

```
def read_file(logs, self):
```

your method try to open the `self` instance instead of logs when you call:

```
self.read_file(logs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `read_file(logs)`, make sure that:

```
logs = "log.txt"
```

If necessary, write the complete path to "log.txt", for instance:

```
logs = "/home/user/log.txt"
```

Also, and I'm not sure if this was a typo in your question, make sure that you declare `read_file` like this:

```
def read_file(self, logs):
```

That is, `self` must come first.

Answer (score 1):

Your `logs` variable would have to be the string "log.txt" for this to work. Apparently it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the file is the problem, maybe its not asccii you could do
import codecs

def read_file(logs,self):
    print 'here'
   f1 = codecs.open( "someFile", "r", "utf-8" )
    f1=open(logs,"r","utf-8")
    for line in f1:
        print str(line)